# JavaScript: document.all.item() replacement

Tags: javascript

I am using `document.all.item("name")` and it works in IE 10 and Google Chrome 29 but not in Firefox. Is there a replacement that is compatible with Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("name")` should do the same thing, but better because it handles the case where there are multiple elements with the same name properly (ie. radio buttons, form arrays, etc.)

Comment: `.item` also finds based on id AFAIK, so the replacement depends on how it's actually being used, right?

Comment: @Jon I thougt that too but it does seem to find elements by name as well, for example `document.all.item('q')` finds the search `<input>` on this page

Comment: @andyb: That's the whole point: it finds both by id *and* name. `getElementsByName` does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findelement(name) {
  if (document.getElementsByName(name))
    return document.getElementsByName(name) ;
  else
    return document.getElementById(name) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old thread which I happened to stumble upon today. A fact we need to consider in replacing `document.all.item` with `document.getElementByName` is that former returns `HTMLCollection` while latter returns `NodeList`. Here is another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-htmlcollection-and-a-nodelist-in-dom) discussing the differences between these two.